# Equilibrium point of a Non linear System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

Consider the Autonomous non linear System $$ x'= y \\
y'=-ky+h(x) $$ with $k \in \mathbb R, k\gt 0$ being a real parameter and $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ a continuous function of $x$ such that $ h(0)=0$ and $ h(x) \neq 0$ for every other $x \neq 0$, and also $h$ is not linear in $x$ (otherwise the whole system would be linear).
I have to determine whether $(0,0)$ is a stable equilibrium point.

My attempt:
I have tried different ways to solve this.
If I study the Jacobian matrix, I need $h'(x) $ (at least $h'(0) $) but $h$ is not said to be differentiable.
If I try to find a Lyapunov function, I don't know how to deal with $h$ in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.
I even tried to determine a function $g$ such that $(x', y') = \nabla g $ and a possible Hamiltonian of the system but it didn't work.

What would you do? Thank you.

Comment: There isn't enough information. Consider $h(x) = x$ and $h(x) = -x.$ Is there some additional context (or constraints) regarding $h$?

Comment: There is only a hint to consider the function $g(x, y) = \frac{1} {2} + \int_0^x h(s) ds $.

Comment: I agree with your comment and edited the post.

Comment: If there isn't a typo in the equations of the system, I suspect there's one in the hint.  I think you'll find the function
$$
f(x,y)={-}\frac{y^2}{2}+\int_0^xh(x)dx
$$
more useful, because
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}f(x,y)&={-}yy'+h(x)x'\\
&=y(h(x)-y')\\
&=ky^2\ ,
\end{align} though I'm not sure whether it helps.